# TALES expression inside id property

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I'm trying to make dynamically created checkboxes on a plone temaplate, using `tal-repeat`. Check the below code for details.

```
<div tal:define="global pessoa python:view.dados_pessoa()" class="drop-element"></div>
<div class="row m-t-10" tal:repeat="telefone python: pessoa.get('telefones', [])">
  <input type="hidden" class="idTelefone" name="telefones.id" value="${python: telefone.get('id', '')}" />
  <div class="col s3 grey-text text-darken-1">
     <input class="grey-text text-darken-1 tipoTelefone" type="text" name="telefones.tipo" value="${python: telefone.get('tipo', '').capitalize()}" autoComplete="off" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col s5">
     <input class="grey-text text-darken-1 numeroTelefone" type="text" name="telefones.numero" value="${python: '(%s) %d' % (telefone.get('ddd', ''), telefone.get('numero', ''))}" autoComplete="false" readonly/>
  </div>
  <div class="col s2">
     <input type="checkbox" id="${python: telefone.get('id', '')}" name="telefones.sms" ${python: 'checked' if telefone.get('sms', '') else ''}>
     <label for="${python: telefone.get('id', '')}" class="active fix-label" style="top: 25px !important">SMS</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field m-t-10 col s2">
     <button type="button" class="sp_btn right red m-t-05 btn-remover-telefone">Remover</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Putting it simple, `pessoa['telefones']` is a list, that can come with 0 or more dictionaries.

The point here is at the lines:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="${python: telefone.get('id', '')}" name="telefones.sms" ${python: 'checked' if telefone.get('sms', '') else ''}>
<label for="${python: telefone.get('id', '')}" class="active fix-label" style="top: 25px !important">SMS</label>
```

As my plone site uses materialize, i need to connect a label to a checkbox via id, else it wont show. Sounds like it will work, since each index on `telefone` have a unique id. The problem is that when that renders, the ID property is rendered as a string of the TALES expression instead of the expression result, like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="${python: telefone.get('id', '')}" name="telefones.sms">
<label for="2138518" class="active fix-label" style="top: 25px !important">SMS</label>
```

Why? how can i get around it? Searched on everything i could, and can't find a solution.

Comment: Please ask Plone questions in our forum, https://community.plone.org where more people will see them and be able to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what Plone version do you use? I ealier version expressions like ${} didn't exist.
What should work al time is somehing like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" tal:attributes="id python: telefone.get('id', '')"> name="telefones.sms">
```

hope that will help you, cheers Maik

Comment: I use version 5.
Using a static name won't help, since i need a unique ID for each loop on the repeat

Comment: what you need to use is tal:attributes